# TCL lappend creates another hierarchy

Tags: list, tcl

See code below:

```
proc forbid args {
   set dict_name [ lindex $args 1 ]
   puts "dict_name llength is: [llength $dict_name ]"
   set listy [ list "\$${dict_name}" ]
   lappend listy [ lindex $args 2 ]
   puts $listy
}
forbid k l m n
exit
```

The code output is:

```
dict_name llength is: 1
{$l} m
```

Why is not `$l m` or `{$l m}`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you are not converting the list to a string when you call `puts`. Because you don't, Tcl has to. When Tcl converts a list to a string it will generate a string that can be guaranteed to be turned back into a list. It does that by adding backslashes and/or curly braces around elements that need some sort of protection.

For example:

```
% puts [list a b c]
a b c
% puts [list \$a \$b \$c]
{$a} {$b} {$c}
```

The curly braces aren't part of the data, it's simply part of the output when converting the list to a string. You can (and often should) change the formatting by explicitly converting the list to a string.

For example, this:

```
puts [join $listy " "]
```

... will result in this:

```
$l m
```